# Que signifie "les mets" dans cette phrase?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

En [répondant](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/94126/34942) sur une question chez https://cooking.stackexchange.com, j'ai traduit cette définition:

> Connaissance de tout ce qui se rapporte à la cuisine, à l'ordonnancement des repas, à l'art de déguster et d'apprécier **les mets**.

en Anglais par:

> The knowledge of everything relating to the kitchen, organisation of meals, up to the art of tasting dishes and appreciating **table decoration**.

puisqu'il me semble logique que "les mets" veut dire "mettre la table", mais je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression jusqu'à maintenant.

*Ai-je fait une erreur ou est-ce correct par coup de chance?*

Comment: Parce que tu *dégustes* les fourchettes la nappe et autres serviettes toi ? Bon! Moi, je préfère déguster les ***dishes*** ... D'ailleurs... c'est l'heure! BonAp'!

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci!  L'original avait déjà été corrigé, mais je laisses celui-ci comme c'est sinon la question n'a plus de sens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Un mets » (toujours avec un **s** final) désigne un plat préparé (élaboré) qui entre dans la composition d'un repas.

Voir [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mets)

Comment: Merci beaucoup!  **+1 et accepté.  :-)**  (et l'original avait déjà été corrigé avant que je puisse lire ceci)